# Problem with updating tlmgr: Bad hostname

Tags: texlive

I just tried to update my texlive-installation but got the following error:

```
sudo tlmgr update --self                                                    
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 500 Can't connect to funnyshare.org:80 (Bad hostname) (for http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.md5)
TLUtils::download_file: persistent connection ok, but download failed: http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.md5
TLUtils::download_file: retrying with wget.
TLUtils::download_file: retry with wget succeeded: http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.md5
Unable to download the remote TeX Live database,
but found a local copy so using that.

You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror;
see the information and examples for the -repository option at
http://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html
(or in the output of install-tl --help).

tlmgr: package repository http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates for tlmgr present.
tlmgr: no updates available

sudo tlmgr update --all                                                                        
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 500 Can't connect to funnyshare.org:80 (Bad hostname) (for http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.md5)
TLUtils::download_file: persistent connection ok, but download failed: http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.md5
TLUtils::download_file: retrying with wget.
TLUtils::download_file: retry with wget succeeded: http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.md5
Unable to download the remote TeX Live database,
but found a local copy so using that.

You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror;
see the information and examples for the -repository option at
http://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html
(or in the output of install-tl --help).

tlmgr: package repository http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

Any idea what my be wrong and how to fix it? I am running this on ubuntu 13.10.

```
tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 31673 (2013-09-16 18:03:22 +0200)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/local/texlive/2013
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2013
```

Comment: Try running multiple times `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` at terminal until you get a good new host connection.

Comment: have you tried changing the mirror/repo by hand? If not, try `sudo tlmgr option repository http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet` and then issue the update command as usual

Comment: Yes, it appears that funnyshare.org is very down, the name does not currently resolve in the domain name service, you better force another mirror manually.

Comment: @student http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/ and http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Bad Hostname` error was caused by the unavailability of the active mirror, which in this case was http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet

This was hinted also in the log:

> You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror;

In such cases it's possible to select a different mirror with:

```
sudo tlmgr option repository <insert another mirror name here>
```

if the default mirror is set to http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (can be called also by the special argument `ctan`) `tlmgr` will pick up a different mirror from the list of active mirrors at each run.

As noted by @texenthusiast the list of up-to-date mirror can be found at [ctan.org/mirrors](http://ctan.org/mirrors) and [ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon](http://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon)